# Recording of h.264 rtsp video stream in VLC

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, video-capture

I try to capture and record to a file rtsp video stream (h.264) from the IP camera using VLC command line in Windows.

I can view the stream using simple:

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://10.1.5.228:554/live.sdp
```

And it works every time. However, when I try to record 30-seconds video, using

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://10.1.5.228:554/live.sdp --sout file/mp4:test.mp4 --run-time=30 vlc://quit
```

results are unstable - sometimes it actually records the video (then its size is about 5 MB), but most often it just creates almost empty mp4 file (it has always 713 bytes).

I think that it may have something in common with h.264 interframe compression (encoded by the camera), but the question is: how to solve this issue and record the stream every time I try.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are simply dumping the rtsp stream into a file, which could be prone to errors. Try to change your sout chain to something like this. Replace X's and path to your environment.

```
 vlc -vvv -I dummy rtsp://10.1.5.228:554/live.sdp --sout='#transcode{venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,no-cabac},vcodec=h264,vb=800,width=XXX,height=XXX,fps=24.0}:std{mux=mp4,dst="/Your/Path/To/recordings/recording_XXX.mp4",access=file}' --network-caching=3000
```

Simply dumping the stream into a file would look like this:

```
 vlc -vvv -I dummy rtsp://10.1.5.228:554/live.sdp --sout='#standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=/Your/Path/recording.mp4}'
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response! Unfortunately in such form it still doesn't work. Where can I find explanations of parameters you used (i.e. profile, level, cabac, vb) and how to check what values should I use?

Comment: (1) Can you post the log output of VLC to see what's going on? (2) You can find the explanation for all the parameters by typing `vlc -H` in the command line - there is an online version, however I doubt it is up to date: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/ (e.g. `profile` defines the H.264 profile to be used such as baseline, main, high etc.)

Comment: there are two informations about errors in the log file: (1) `core error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called` (2) `core error: cannot continue streaming due to errors`. I put whole log file [here](https://jpst.it/GDri)

Comment: Can you try the command with different `--network-caching` parameter settings. The caching value is set in milliseconds. I updated the answer with the new command. Also try `--live-caching` with different values.

Comment: I spend a lot of time, and still nothing. Sometimes it works, but most often it doesn't... But every time I play this same stream in the GUI mode and click the "Record" button - the output video is perfect. Is there any function executable from the command line, that does exactly what this button does?

Comment: (1) I Just updated my answer with another command which should simply dump your stream into a mp4 file
(2) Another approach would be to check the log output when clicking the recording button - look for the sout chain being defined as `using sout chain: ...`

Comment: hello , late comment , it may not be about h.264,may be about the audio codec it multicast with video, in vlc aac codec is experimental right now so I think this is the reason for this. I have the problem you have and when i multicast without audio, the record is fine.